# Is moving the <header> tag bad/ not allowed for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility

In our (Angular and Material based) project, we have a situation where we conditionally move the header tag deeper into the DOM:

```html
<header *ngIf="sidenavigation.isOpen">
  ...
</header>

<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <header *ngIf="!sidenavigation.isOpen">
      ...
    </header>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

This has styling related reasons.

I wonder now if this is bad practice especially related to accessibility and screen readers.

Comment: Your title asks about _moving_, but it sounds like you're really asking about _placement_. You might clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've only posted angular code, and not the full rendered HTML, it's a little difficult to provide a thorough and comprehensive answer.

If the conditional movement of the header tag happens at the time of page load and doesn't change, then I don't think that it will be an issue.

However, if the movement happens after the page has already loaded, then it could potentially be confusing, as content would be moving around the page. The extent of the issue would be determined by what content is present in the header element.

If the header element contains navigation structures, then it could be a possible violation of [3.2.3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/consistent-navigation.html) or [3.2.4](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/consistent-identification.html). If it contains help text, like documentation or contact information, then it could be a violation of [3.2.6](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/consistent-help.html).

Comment: Yes, there's no rule that says the [header element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) must be at the top or outside of the document. The answer with respect to accessibility depends on the overall structure of your page.